# Cómo se usa y para qué sirve "Return"

Tags: python, retorno

[image: estoy queriendo entender esto y no lo entiendo]Hola muy buenas. Soy un principiante en programación y estoy haciendo un curso de introducción a la programación con Python en Udemy y cuando escribo esto (tal cual al ejemplo que da en el curso), no me lo toma, me dice que hay un error. Mi pregunta claramente es muy tonta, pero soy un principiante y quiero entender bien todas las cosas

Answer (score 1):

Octavio,

En la parte de abojo de VSCcode tienes la consola que dice: **Problemas, salida, consulta de depuracion y terminal.**

En el terminal si los simbolos `>>>` estan presentes quiere decir que estas en el ambiente de python, en este caso si intentas correr el archivo 04-Funciones-3.py de esta manera `python 04-Funciones-3.py` tendras un error de sintaxis ( syntax error).
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Trata de hacer lo siguinete, en el terminal, donde vez `>>>` coloca `exti()` luego de este comando el terminal te debe mostrar algo como `PS C:\User\Octovio`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No es un problema del codigo, es un problema de como se esta intentando lanzar el interprete python, o desde que contexto se quiere lanzar.